# ServiceStack empty metadata

Tags: servicestack

Seeing a strange problem, getting empty metata pages for xml,json and jvs.
Using the following command line app. How does one debug these issues?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public struct NativeUser
    {
        public int login;
        public string group;
        public string name;
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class User
    {
        private NativeUser _native;

        public User() { }


        public User(NativeUser native)
        {
            _native = native;
        }

        public static implicit operator NativeUser(User user)
        {
            return user._native;
        }

        public static implicit operator User(NativeUser native)
        {
            return new User(native);
        }

        // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
        [DataMember]
        public int login
        {
            get { return _native.login; }
            set { _native.login = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string group
        {
            get { return _native.group; }
            set { _native.group = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string name
        {
            get { return _native.name; }
            set { _native.name = value; }
        }
    }


    [Description("GET account, all or by list of groups or by list of logins")]
    [Route("/accounts/{groups}", "GET")]
    [Route("/accounts/{logins}", "GET")]
    [Route("/accounts/", "GET")]
    public class Accounts : IReturn<User[]>
    {
        public string[] groups { set; get; }
        public int[] logins { set; get; }

        public Accounts() { }

        public Accounts(params int[] logins)
        {
            this.logins = logins;
        }

        public Accounts(params string[] groups)
        {
            this.groups = groups;
        }
    }

    public class Host : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public Host() : base("Test", 
                            typeof(Accounts).Assembly)
        {

        }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Servce : IService
    {
        public object Get(Accounts request)
        {
            return new List<User>(){new User(new NativeUser())};
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new Host();
            host.Init();
            host.Start("http://+:12345/");

            global::System.Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nm, found the bug :

```
public class Accounts : IReturn<User[]>
```

needs to be

```
public class Accounts : IReturn<List<User>>
```

Another very note worthy thing: All DTO's and objects being passed back and fourth in the DTO's require an empty constructor in order for the metata data to be properly generated.
Not sure if this is by design or a bug

Comment: By design. metadata pages need to be able to create instance of your DTOs, for this it needs a parameterless constructor.